Relationship between two matrices whose sum and difference are similar matrices
Let $A$ and $B$ be hermitian $n$-by-$n$ matrices with complex coefficients with the property that $A+B$ and $A-B$ are similar, i.e. there is a unitary $U$ such that $A+B = U(A-B)U^\dagger$. Does it follow that there exists a unitary $Q$ such that $QAQ^\dagger$ is a real-symmetric matrix and $QBQ^\dagger$ is an imaginary skew-symmetric matrix (is a real skew-symmetric matrix multiplied by the imaginary unit)?
Indeed, if A and B are real-symmetric and imaginary skew-symmetric, respectively, then $A+B$ and $A-B$ are clearly similar as they are complex conjugates of each other (and hence transposes of each due to hermiticity). I'm curious to know if the more general case can be reduced to this by a single unitary $Q$.
